# Get java installed path using batch file?

Tags: java, batch-file, path, command, java-home

- I need to set JAVA_HOME variable using batch script
- Tried below codes, but no use.

> for /f %%j in ("java.exe") do @echo.%%~dp$PATH:j

the above script gives empty

> FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=2*" %%A IN ('REG QUERY
>   "HKLM\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" /v CurrentVersion')
>   DO set CurVer=%%B

the above script gives 1.6

> dir java.exe /B /S

the above script gives C:\Windows\System32 but actually java installed in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31

- I need to set JAVA_HOME as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31.

How to get this?

Answer (score 4):

I got solution. this gives exactly the installed path.

```
FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=2*" %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit" /v CurrentVersion') DO
set CurVer=%%B ECHO %CurVer%


FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=2*" %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\%CurVer%" /v JavaHome')
DO set JavaPath=%%B ECHO %JavaPath%
```

Comment: Tried the second one with hardcoding the version to 1.8. However, JavaPath is only being fetched till `C:\Program` . I guess we need to work on the whitespace in `Program Files`

Answer (score 3):

Path to Java 1.6 `JavaHome`:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL 
FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%a IN ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.6" /v JavaHome') DO set "JavaHome16=%%b"
ECHO %JavaHome16%
```

Path to Java 1.7 `JavaHome`:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL 
FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%a IN ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.7" /v JavaHome') DO set "JavaHome17=%%b"
ECHO %JavaHome17%
```

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
setx JAVA_HOME "path/to/it"
```

get it by doing `%JAVA_HOME%`

Comment: How "path/to/it" will get java path? i tried, its setting JAVA_HOME as path/to/it

Comment: @BobbyRachel sorry, i meant for you to  replace that with your path. and i answered your how to set it question not how to get it.

Comment: its ok.. i know how to set. the problem is getting.

Comment: before setting the path, if i get it using %JAVA_HOME% means, it will give empty value.

Comment: @BobbyRachel updated it.

Comment: @BobbyRachel You have to have it set first

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33745/discussion-between-susan-yanders-and-bobby-rachel)

Comment: i guess, yet you aren't clear about my question. to set JAVA_HOME i need java installed path rite? after getting its path, i can set JAVA_HOME. i need that path to set JAVA_HOME

Comment: @BobbyRachel Your computer most likely wont have the java home variable. You add that yourself

Comment: yep... but java home is not the only way to get its path. while installing every program, it will make an entry in registry. so possibly java will do an entry after installation. so its possible to get its path from registry, but i do not know how.

Comment: @BobbyRachel Oh. you have gone beyond my knowledge. What are you trying to do anyways?

Answer (score 0):

This will work if your JAVA_HOME is configured.save this as someName.bat and run.

```
echo 
   where java
pause
```

OK then use this, By running this will creates a text file where same place you put this bat contains the JAVA path

```
 @ECHO OFF
SET TITLE=JavaHome.bat
TITLE=%TITLE%
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET JDKBIN=\bin
SET JREBIN=\jre\bin
SET JBINARY=%JREBIN%\java.exe
SET SCRIPTDIR=%~dp0
SET SCRIPTDIR=%SCRIPTDIR:~0,-1%
IF EXIST "%SCRIPTDIR%\javahome.txt" (
ECHO.
ECHO JDK home already set in javahome.txt file.
GOTO :LOCKFILE
)
IF DEFINED JAVA_HOME (
ECHO.
ECHO JAVA_HOME is already set to !JAVA_HOME!
CALL :STRIP "!JAVA_HOME!">"!SCRIPTDIR!\javahome.txt"
ECHO Created !SCRIPTDIR!\javahome.txt file containing JAVA_HOME
GOTO :END
)
SET "dir=%~f0"
:DIRLOOP
CALL :FGETDIR "%dir%"
IF EXIST "%dir%\%JBINARY%" (
ECHO Parent directory search found JAVA_HOME at %dir%
GOTO :SEARCHSET
)
IF "%dir:~-1%" == ":" (
ECHO Parent directory search reached root and "%JBINARY%" was not found.
GOTO :REGISTRY
)
GOTO :DIRLOOP
:SEARCHSET
SET JAVA_HOME=%dir%
ECHO %JAVA_HOME%>javahome.txt
ECHO Created file %SCRIPTDIR%\javahome.txt with value %JAVA_HOME%
GOTO :END
:REGISTRY
:: registry search section
:: runs only when JAVA_HOME not set, file search fails, and javahome.txt doesn't exist
ECHO Searching registry for JAVA_HOME...
ECHO. 2>merged.txt
ECHO. 2>list.txt
ECHO. 2>uniquelist.txt
IF NOT EXIST reg32.txt ECHO. 2>reg32.txt
IF NOT EXIST reg64.txt ECHO. 2>reg64.txt
START /w REGEDIT /e reg32.txt "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit"
TYPE reg32.txt | FIND "JavaHome" > merged.txt
START /w REGEDIT /e reg64.txt "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit"
TYPE reg64.txt | FIND "JavaHome" >> merged.txt
FOR /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%x IN (merged.txt) DO (
CALL :STRIP "%%~x" >>list.txt
)
FOR /F "tokens=* delims= " %%a IN (list.txt) DO (
SET str=%%a
FIND /I ^"!str!^" list.txt>nul
FIND /I ^"!str!^" uniquelist.txt>nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO !str!>>uniquelist.txt
)
:PROMPT
ECHO Select a JDK from the list:
SET /A COUNT=0
FOR /f "tokens=1,* delims=" %%y IN (uniquelist.txt) DO (
SET /A COUNT += 1
ECHO !COUNT!: %%~y
)
SET /P NUMBER=Type a number here:
IF "%NUMBER%" GTR "%COUNT%" GOTO :PROMPT
SET /A COUNT=0
FOR /f "tokens=1,* delims=" %%z IN (uniquelist.txt) DO (
SET /A COUNT += 1
IF !COUNT!==!NUMBER! (
SET JAVA_HOME=%%~z
)
)
ECHO %JAVA_HOME%>javahome.txt
GOTO CLEANUP

:: batch functions section
:FGETDIR
SET "dir=%~dp1"
SET "dir=%dir:~0,-1%"
EXIT /B 0
:STRIP
REM Strip quotes and extra backslash from string
SET n=%~1
SET n=%n:\\=\%
SET n=%n:"=%
IF NOT "%n%"=="" ECHO %n%
GOTO :EOF
:: cleanup and end
:CLEANUP
REM cleanup of registry search
DEL /Q merged.txt
DEL /Q list.txt
DEL /Q uniquelist.txt
DEL /Q reg32.txt
DEL /Q reg64.txt
GOTO :LOCKFILE
:: if all fails
:FAILED
IF NOT DEFINED JAVA_HOME (
ECHO Error: JAVA_HOME not set in system vars, file search failed, && javahome.txt didn't exist.
GOTO :END
)
:LOCKFILE
ECHO.
SET /P JAVA_HOME=<"%SCRIPTDIR%\javahome.txt"
ECHO The file %SCRIPTDIR%\javahome.txt shows JAVA_HOME to be %JAVA_HOME%
:END
FOR /l %%a in (30,-1,1) do (TITLE %TITLE% -- Closing in %%as&ping -n 2 -w 1 127.0.0.1>NUL)
```

FYI : original reference: https://gist.github.com/djangofan/1445440

Comment: JAVA_HOME configured means? its giving, C:\Windows\System32\java.exe. i want program files location.